# PHP Echo session then unset

Tags: php, session

I am trying to echo a session and then unset it.
I have this code:

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['error']))
    {
    ?>
          <div class="alert alert-danger" style="border-radius:0;margin-bottom:0;">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> &nbsp; <?php echo $_SESSION['error'];unset($_SESSION['error']);?>
          </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

I think the session is destroyed before it is echoed.

**I fixed this now :)**

```
$_SESSION['error'] = 'Error message!';
$user->redirect('index.php');
exit(); --> this exit fixed it
```

and then

```
if(isset($_SESSION['error']))
{
echo $_SESSION['error'];unset($_SESSION['error']);
}
```

Comment: did you start the session? (in all files)

Comment: Yes, I did. @Fred-ii-

Comment: How do you assign $_SESSION['error']?

Comment: $_SESSION['error'] = "Error message"; @Switcher

Comment: Well, my only opinion is session is started somewhere else, or after the variable assignment.

Comment: The session is started here: require_once 'php/db/config.php';  @Switcher

Answer (score 0):

Call `session_start();` on the beggining of your php code in order to work with sessions.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['error']))
    //...
```

If the session is started and the HTML part is not showing, is because there is no such index `'`error`'` in your sessions.

Comment: I've removed my answer about session_destroy when I've noticed OP doesn't want to unset __session__ , He wants to unset the variable in session :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['error']))
{
?>
      <div class="alert alert-danger" style="border-radius:0;margin-bottom:0;">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> &nbsp; <?php echo $_SESSION['error']; ?>
      </div>
<?php
}
unset($_SESSION['error']);
?>
```

Try that. Untested on my side though.